# Is it possible to exchange Spintria?

Tags: cultist-simulator

Is there a way to exchange one Silver Spintria into two Bronze Spintrias?

Or even get two Iron Spintria and get one Bronze Spintria?

I know it's possible to sell them for normal money but that's not what I'm looking for.